# mysql query select limit when insert date column less than 10

Tags: mysql, sql, select, limit

I need a MYSQL query to select only latest 10 records order by insertDate, but I can't fix limit 10 because maybe some record have had same date and I want all column data in latest 10 distinct insertDate rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a sub-query to find 10'th latest insertDate:

```
select * from tablename
where insertDate >= (select DISTINCT insertDate from tablename
                     order by insertDate desc limit 9,1)
order by insertDate desc
```

I'm not sure if you want that `DISTINCT` in the sub-select or not. (I guess not...)

Comment: I think that should be `limit 9, 1`.

Comment: Probably. Does limit 9,1 mean skip 9, or pick the 9:th?

Comment: that would return just 1 row.

Comment: `limit 9, 1` means to skip 9 rows and choose the next 1.  `limit 0, 1` chooses the first row.